# mirt: GRM with symmetrical thresholds

Tags: r, item-response-theory, mirt

I'm looking for a way to fit a graded response model where the thresholds are symmetrically located around zero. The `mirt.model` command allows you to add an equality constrain, but I haven't found a way to implement the constraint `d1 = -d4` and `d2 = -d3`.

Do you know if this is possible with the `mirt` package?

Comment: This would be an unusual identification constraint. You could (I think) do this in a structural equation model (which is equivalent) but you could only do it for one item, because the other items will have different thresholds. (It's also unlikely to be correct - you're turning 4 thresholds into two).

Comment: Thanks @jeremy-miles , I've been thinking about that option too. However, I have a lot of missing data in the data matrix, which is okay within the IRT paradigm, but I think lavaan would have difficulty with it.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I would guess that if you really needed to do this, you'd need to code it yourself (or maybe dig into the MIRT code to tweak it). But that would be a challenge.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm gonna have to. I wanted to avoid it. And otherwise, the model is in fact correct - the problem I'm dealing with actually assumes symmetric thresholds around zero. That's why it seems wasteful to estimate 4 parameters when 2 is enough. Or there's another way to just ignore it, since even if I leave the thresholds unconstrained, they come out almost symmetric (e.g. $2.800, 0.238, -0.216, -2.824$).

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Is there any way to force a mixed model to do it? (I'm not sure there is, just thinking out loud).

Comment: There are various ways to to this with the package. Perhaps playing around with the non-linear optimizers would be helpful (there's examples on the wiki). But failing that, you could just write the functional form yourself using the `createItem()` function.

Comment: @philchalmers I'm glad you showed up. I was literally thinking of you when writing the question. I'll check the methods you suggest. Thanks!